# Onclick without reload page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 url like this:

```
    <td><a href='infomation/gc_details_2.php?id=<?php echo $row['trans_id']?>'><input type='button' id="yes"  value='Yes'></a></td>
    <td><a href='infomation/del_notifi_2.php?id=<?php echo $row['trans_id']?>'><input type='button' value='No'></a></td>
```

When onclick button `Yes` it request to `gc_details_2.php` and reload all page with search result. Now i want when click button `Yes` without reload page. How should i do? Thank all

Comment: Both the anchor and button are going to capture clicks, style the anchors to look like buttons instead.

Comment: Have you check your console, it gives any error?

Comment: Trying to clarify your intent, 
1) Are you trying to send GET requests based on which button is clicked? If so, what should the browser do when it receives the data from the request(GET request should ideally only get data and not modify anything on server). 
2) If you are trying to send some data/update data on server, then it should be a POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE request.
On both the cases, you would be better off having Buttons triggering JS Ajax calls to server as you don't want a page refresh that accompanies anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

For example:

```
 $('#yes').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: your_url,
      type: (GET or POST),
      data: {data: your_data},
      success: function(response) {
         alert('Success!');
       }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ajax instead. Also, It's not good practice to use button inside link. Either you go with link or button. I have removed link here and used button.

**HTML:**

```
<td><input type='button' id="yes" value='Yes' trans_id="<?php echo $row['trans_id']?>"></td>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#yes").click(function(){
    var trans_id=$(this).attr("trans_id");
    $.ajax({
        url:'infomation/gc_details_2.php',
        data:{
            "id":trans_id
        },
        type:"GET",
        success:function(data){
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The button doesn't have any param "trans_id" so your var trans_id value would be undefined. Now that you've edited your answer.. Why not just use an anchor tag and capture the href value?

Comment: Please check html part button @Black 23

Comment: i tried but when i click on button. nothing change :(

Comment: `input` as `button` won't redirect though. Anyway changed code, added `return false` would stop it being redirect. Check now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
    <td><input type='button' id="yes"  class="<?php echo $row['trans_id']?>" value='Yes'></td>

    $("#yes").click(function(){
        var trans_id=$(this).attr("class");
        $.ajax({
           url:'infomation/gc_details_2.php',
            data:{"id":trans_id},      
            type:"GET",
            success:function(data){
alert("ssfasfas");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This would really hinder the ability to use any meaningful classes for the input.

Comment: Classes are meant for CSS markup, not to hold data. data-* attributes are for that, or in this case, we can use an anchor attribute that already contains the link in valid HTML markup.

Comment: i tried but when i click on button. nothing change :(

Comment: did you put alert in success?

Comment: it not showing alert, there was nothing occur. The page is not load :(

Comment: or  I have to do in `gc_detail_2.php`. My code in `gc_detail_2.php`:
`<?php
$trans_id = $_GET['id'];
......
//mycode here
.......
?>`

Comment: echo $_GET['id'] in gc_detail_2.php and tell what is coming?

Comment: if i write follow my code, when `echo  '$_GET['id']'` in `gc_detail_2.php` it will show parameter on url. And if i try follow your code, it not doing something and nothing orrcur

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest of all `$('#yes').click(function(){
        $.get('gc_details_2.php', function(data) {
            $('html').html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });`
And it ***Always works***

Comment: it not work :( and it redirect to `gc_details_2.php`

Comment: wrap that within `$(function(){  });`

Answer (score 1):

Style your anchor tags to have your desired button effect, and dump the button:

**Html:**

```
<a href="infomation/gc_details_2.php?id=<?=$row['trans_id']?>" class="button ajax-fetch">Yes</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(".ajax-fetch").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   jQuery.get(jQuery(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
      jQuery("#result").html(data);
   });
});
```

**Result container:**

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

This will catch any object that you click on with the class "ajax-fetch" and follow the href, then load it into the result div. Use some CSS to style the button class.

Comment: it not work :( and it redirect to `gc_details_2.php`

Comment: Using my html for the anchor tag is important, because it has the class "ajax-fetch" which is what jQuery is going to bind to.

Comment: i know result will show in `div result` but when i click button it still redirect to `gc_details_2.php`

Comment: No button. Remove the button from inside the anchor tag.

Comment: oh, sorry i wrong. But i copied your code and inserted to my code and nothing change. Result still as that

Comment: I can't make it any simpler. Just make sure that the javascript is at the bottom of the page. Best of luck.

Comment: when i write js at the bottom of the page. Nothing to occur :(